# Simple FTP Client C++

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp

I'm attempting to create a simple FTP client in C/C++ that will do simple operations (connect, retrieve file). What I have working so far is the connection and login. I connect using sockets onto port 21, like any regular FTP client. The trouble I'm having is connecting to the port that is specified when the command PASV is entered. I get the message, parse it, then calculate the port from the replay message when PASV is entered.

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (a1, a2, a3, a4, p1, p2) 
DataPort = (p1 * 256) + p2
```

Once I have the port, I try to create another socket and connecting to it the same way. That's where my issues are. My code so far is posted below. I don't know if I need to get the server address again the same way. I'm not getting a response back from the server (if I'm actually suppose to get one, I don't know) Please ask any questions or concerns, thanks.

```
const int FTP_PORT = 21;        // Server Port
const int SIZE = 1024;          // Size of Buffers
char receiveBuff[SIZE];         // Buffer to send to the server
char sendBuff[SIZE];            // Buffer to receive from server
char pasvBuff[] = "pasv";       // Buffer to see if PASV Command was entered
char quitBuff[] = "QUIT";       // Buffer to see if QUIT Command was entered
char pasvMessage[100];          // String for PASV information

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int length = 0, i=0;
    int a1, a2, a3, a4, p1, p2, dataPort;       //PASV Information

    /* Get Server Name from User */
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " server" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    /* Obtain Host (Server) Info  */
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (host == (struct hostent *)NULL)
    {
        perror("Client: gethostbyname");
        return 2;
    }

    /* Add Server Information */
    struct sockaddr_in servAdr;             // Internet address of server
    memset(&servAdr, 0, sizeof(servAdr));   // Clear structure
    servAdr.sin_family = AF_INET;           // Set address typedef
    memcpy(&servAdr.sin_addr, host->h_addr, host->h_length);
    servAdr.sin_port = htons(FTP_PORT);     // Use FTP port

    /* Create Socket to Connect to FTP Server */
    int origSock;                   // Original socket in client
    if ((origSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Client: generate error");
        return 3;
    }

    /* Connect to FTP Server on Port 21 */
    if (connect(origSock, (struct sockaddr *)&servAdr, sizeof(servAdr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Client: connect error");
        return 4;
    }

    /* Get Conenct Message and Print to Screen */
    read(origSock, receiveBuff, sizeof(receiveBuff) - 1);
    write(fileno(stdout), receiveBuff, sizeof(receiveBuff) - 1);

    do
    {
        /* Clear Buffers */
        memset(receiveBuff, 0, SIZE);
        memset(sendBuff, 0, SIZE);

        write(fileno(stdout), "Please enter a FTP Command: ", 28);      // Write User Interface
        read(fileno(stdin), sendBuff, SIZE);                            // Read Command from User
        send(origSock, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff) , 0);                 // Send Command to Server

        read(origSock, receiveBuff, sizeof(receiveBuff) - 1);           // Read Response from Server
        write(fileno(stdout), receiveBuff, sizeof(receiveBuff) - 1);    // Print Response from Server to screen

        /* If PASV Command was Entered */
        if (strncmp(sendBuff, pasvBuff, 4) == 0)
        {
            sscanf(receiveBuff, "227 Entering Passive Mode (%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d)", &a1,&a2,&a3,&a4,&p1,&p2);
            dataPort = (p1 * 256) + p2;

            struct sockaddr_in servAdr2;                // Internet address of server
            memset(&servAdr2, 0, sizeof(servAdr2));     // Clear structure
            servAdr2.sin_family = AF_INET;              // Set address typedef
            memcpy(&servAdr2.sin_addr, host->h_addr, host->h_length);
            servAdr.sin_port = htons(dataPort);         // Use FTP port

            /* Create Socket to Connect to FTP Server */
            int dataSock;                               // Data socket in client
            if ((dataSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
            {
                perror("Client: generate error");
                return 3;
            }

            /* Connect to FTP Server on Data Port */
            if (connect(dataSock, (struct sockaddr *)&servAdr, sizeof(servAdr)) < 0)
            {
                perror("Client: connect error");
                return 4;
            }

            read(dataSock, receiveBuff, sizeof(receiveBuff) - 1);
            write(fileno(stdout), receiveBuff, sizeof(receiveBuff) - 1);
        }

    } while (strncmp(sendBuff, quitBuff, 4) != 0);      // Go until QUIT Command is entered

    close(origSock);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "C/C++" is not a thing.

Comment: _"I'm not getting a response back from the server "_ Way too broad. There are so many situations this can happen. Firewalls, NAT mappings, port restrictions. Especially you should check for any error conditions, you may meet at the socket operations.

Comment: Pretty much, I'm seeing if I'm actually doing the second connection correctly? That's where I'm having trouble, I thought I would get some kind of response back from the server.

Comment: You need to look at the return value of your `read()` to find out how much data you actually read from your sockets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send command to FTP server using sockets in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377614/send-command-to-ftp-server-using-sockets-in-c)

Comment: When I do the read after the second connect, I sit there since I'm getting nothing to read back.

Comment: Because there is nothing to read yet.  You haven't sent any command to tell the server to actually sending any data.  `PASV` simply opens the server's data port.  You have to send `STOR` and `RETR` commands to perform transfers over the open data port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are parsing the `PASV` reply, you are populating the `servAdr2` variable, except for its `sin_port` field.  You are assigning the reported port to the `servAdr.sin_port` field instead.  You are then connecting the data socket using `servAdr` instead of `servAdr2`.  So, you are effectively connecting the data socket to the original IP address of the server on the reported port, instead of connecting to the reported IP address (which can be different than the server IP).  `a1`-`a4` are the IPv4 octets of the IP address you should be connecting to.

That said, if the server supports the `EPSV` command, you really should use that instead.  It is much easier to parse then `PASV`, as `PASV` does not have a standardized format (so be prepared to parse multiple vendor-specific formats). `EPSV` solves that problem by standardizing the format in a machine-parsable manner.

As for why you are not getting any response, it is because you are not telling the server to send any files over the open data connection.  Sending `PASV` merely opens the server's data port.  After you connect to it, you then have to send a `STOR` or `RETR` command on the control socket to actually perform a file transfer over the data socket.  You also have to read the server's final response on the control socket after the transfer is finished, before you can then send any new commands.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have the transfer working mostly. I do PASV (open data port), then do RETR (to control port), I read on the control port and get a 150 code. I read the data port and display the text from the text document. After that though, my program hangs, it seems like its waiting for a read but its not. I saw you mentioned that I must read the final response from the control port, which I tried but I'm still hanging.

Comment: It sounds like you are not handling the case where the server closes the data connection to signal EOF.  You have to read from the data socket until it is disconnected, THEN read the response from the control socket to complete the transfer.  And BTW, the way you are reading responses is completely wrong.  You are not accounting for the fact that TCP is a streaming transport, `read()` can return fewer bytes than requested, and has no concept of protocols. FTP is a textual line-based protocol, so you should be reading the control socket in CRLF-delimited lines, not in raw buffers.

Comment: Do I specifically close the port in the client, or does the server have to end it. How can I detect when the server sends the EOF signal?

Comment: The sender closes its end of the data connection to signal EOF, and then the receiver closes its end for cleanup. For `RETR`, the server closes the connection when it is done sending the file to you. For `STOR`, you close the data socket when you are done sending a file to the server. As for how to detect a disconnect, `read()` will tell you that, so you have to pay attention to its return value: < 0 = error, 0 = disconnect, > 0 = bytes read. Though you really should be using `recv()` instead of `read()` (same rules apply to `recv()` though).

Comment: Seems that you have not learned the basics of TCP programming before delving head-first into FTP, which is built on top of TCP.  You might want to take a step back and focus on just learning the proper way to handle TCP programming, you appear to have a bit to learn still, which you can then apply to FTP programming afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

This is a C++ sockets library I wrote that does that has a FTP client (connect, retrieve list and files). The comments in the code explain

https://github.com/pedro-vicente/lib_netsockets

Basically:

FTP uses two TCP connections to transfer files : a control connection and a data connection

connect a socket(control socket) to a ftp server on the port 21

receive on the socket a message from the ftp server(code : 220)

send login to the ftp server using the command USER and wait for confirmation 
(331)

send password using the command PASS and wait for confirmation that you are logged on the server (230)

receive file:

use the passive mode: send command PASV

receive answer with an IP address and a port (227), parse this message.

connect a second socket(a data socket) with the given configuration

use the command RETR on the control socket

receive data through the data socket, close data socket.

leave session using on the control socket the command QUIT.